# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Blob>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I want to implement file download using this Angular 6 code:

Rest API:

```
@GetMapping("export")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> export() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));
    }
```

Service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/index";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import {HttpUtils} from "../common/http-utils";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DownloadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  downloadPDF(): any {
    return this.http.get(environment.api.urls.downloads.getPdf, { responseType: 'blob' }).map(
    (res) => {
        return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    });
  }  
}
```

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DownloadService} from "../service/download.service";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {flatMap} from "rxjs/internal/operators";
import {of} from "rxjs/index";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-download',
  templateUrl: './download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./download.component.scss']
})
export class DownloadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
  }

  export() {               
    this.downloadService.downloadPDF().subscribe(res => {
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    });         
  } 
}
```

When I start angular I get error: ERROR in src/app/panel/service/download.service.ts(17,91): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

What is the proper wya to import `map` into the code?
When I clink download button nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably using Rxjs 5.5 or later.

You can no longer chain operators like `map` directly on an Observable Value after Rxjs 5.5. You'll have to use `.pipe` and then pass the comma separated list of operators instead.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
downloadPDF(): any {
  return this.http.get(environment.api.urls.downloads.getPdf, {
    responseType: 'blob',
    observe: 'response'
  })
  .pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    })
  );
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-image-blob-service?file=src/app/image.service.ts) for your ref.

BTW, [**Explorer**](https://reactive.how/rxjs/explorer) is an amazing tool to check how the Rxjs syntax has changed so far.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get `ERROR in src/app/panel/service/download.service.ts(21,30): error TS2339: Property 'blob' does not exist on type 'Blob'.`

Comment: @PeterPenzov, specify it's type as `any`. And that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the request something like this because you're using angular 6

```
downloadPDF(): any {
    return this.http.get(environment.api.urls.downloads.getPdf, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

UPDATE : 
import `ResponseContentType`

> import {Http, ResponseContentType} from '@angular/http';

Comment: I get `ERROR in src/app/panel/service/download.service.ts(19,81): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ResponseContentType'.`

Comment: I get ERROR in src/app/panel/service/download.service.ts(21,65): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ responseType: ResponseContentType; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type 'ResponseContentType' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

Comment: please check now